# Accessing commit details of a specific file using jgit in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jgit

I have been trying to get git comit log for a specific file in git repo, but after multiple attempts I am failing to identify the source of the problem.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/tusharbanne/fileAccess) to my github code.

PS: The files Folder needs to be deleted everytime the app needs to start again. Any tips on that would be also helpful.

To put it in short, I tried the below piece of code to get the commit log, but I am getting a **null** RevCommit.

```
Repository repository = git.getRepository();

//Approach 1
    RevCommit commits = git.log().addPath("D:/Code_downloads/fileaccess/files/dev/Doc2.csv").call().iterator().next();
    


//Approach 2
    RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk( repository );
       revWalk.markStart( revWalk.parseCommit( repository.resolve( Constants.HEAD ) ) );
       revWalk.setTreeFilter(PathFilter.create( "D:/Code_downloads/fileaccess/files/dev/Doc2.csv" ) );
       revWalk.sort( RevSort.COMMIT_TIME_DESC );
       revWalk.sort( RevSort.REVERSE, true );
       RevCommit commit = revWalk.next();
```

Referred multiple documentations and stackoverflow posts. no luck.
https://archive.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.5.0.201609210915-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/LogCommand.html

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It should work to use `addPath()` and then iterate over the `RevCommits`.

But you should not use the "absoulte path" to the file, but rather only the relative path inside your repository.

E.g.

```
Iterable<RevCommit logs = git.log().addPath("README.md").call();
for (RevCommit rev : logs) {
    System.out.println("Commit: " + rev + ", name: " + rev.getName() + ", id: " + rev.getId().getName());
}
```

There is a ready-to-run [snippet](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowLog.java) in the [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/) which shows a few more ways to iterate commits.